# Is there an advantage to cutting joints in concrete rather than tooling them?

Tags: concrete

There were a few concrete driveways poured in my neighborhood this year. The contractor (largest in the area) took, what I always thought was, an unconventional approach to the joints.  Typically, I would expect them to pour the concrete, and then tool the joints in.  This company poured the driveways on one day, then returned a day later to cut the joints in with saws.

Is there some advantage to cutting the joints, as opposed to tooling them?

Comment: Quicker, easier, faster = cheaper...

Comment: Possibly also less cracking.

Comment: They wait at least a day before saw cutting. It can actually crack in that time if it is curing too fast. Just a thought. I have a driveway that was saw cut and it still cracked elsewhere.

Comment: Our pool deck did in fact crack in one place before they came back with the saw just 14 hours later.  Poured on very hot summer afternoon. The surface wet with water til after sundown, by morning there was already a crack.  In general tho, tooled joints aren’t that deep and serve more to break surface tension and encourage the crack to that location.  Sawcuts are much deeper and actually allow for some expansion and contraction.